# Count how many times a word occurs in a file and email if word appears 5+ times

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script that counts how many times the word "bad" exits in a file, and if it exists it will send an email alert.

I am trying to get the script to send an email only if the word "bad" occurs five or more times, and do nothing if the word occurs less than five.

I am also trying to make it so that, if the word "bad" occurs five or more times, then start the count after five for the email alert.

For example, if the word "bad" occurs seven times then the email alert says that the word bad occurs three times (always ignoring the first five times the word "bad" occurs in the file).

Example of the output file

```
bad
bad
bad
bad
bad
bad
bad
```

since the word "bad" occurs seven times, an email alert should go out saying the word "bad" has been recorded three times.

Here is the code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $file = 'output.txt';
my $mark = 'bad';

open my $f, "<$file" or die "Error open file: $!\n";

my $counter = 0;

while ( my $line = <$f> ) {

    if ( $line =~ /$mark/ ) {
        $counter++;
    }
}

if ( $counter ) {

    my $body      = "Warning the word bad was recorded $counter times";
    my $cmd_email = "echo $body | mailx -s \"Alert error\" tneal01\@gmail.com";
    system($cmd_email) == 0 or die "Error sending email -- $!";
}
```

Comment: I think that when you say *exits* you mean *exists*. I've edited your question to use *occurs*, which is better English, but *appears* is also possible. You may roll back my edit if you prefer

Answer (score 1):

simple solution would be using comparison operator

```
if ( $counter > 5 ) {
     $counter -=  5;
     ........
     .......
}
```

**if** control structure executes only if its condition returns a true value.

Comment: You need to subtract `4`, not `5`. The OP gives the example (twice) of `7` vs `3` so I think they start counting _at_ `5` (so it's `==1` for `5`).